# Excel Pivot Table - Average Occupancy by Month, when Date is a Count

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a Pivot table to handle 100,000+ rows of raw data from hotel reservation.

How do I create a pivot table where I "Count" the number of entries that match by date, but then I want to average that count over the month.

My raw data looks like this:

- DaysOutRound, is a rounded form of how many days out the reservation was booked
- Period, composed by the month number, and the code WEEK (for weekdays) and END (for weekend)

This is a highly simplified version, obviously I sell more than just 1 or 2 rooms per night in a hotel with over 100+ rooms.

```
Date     Type Rate   Market DaysOutRound Month Week Period
7/1/2010 1KN  $99.00 TRAN   1-30         7     WEEK 7-WEEK
7/1/2010 2DN  $99.00 TRAN   0            7     WEEK 7-WEEK
7/2/2010 1KN  $94.00 PREF   0            7     WEEK 7-WEEK
7/2/2010 2DN  $94.00 DISC   0            7     WEEK 7-WEEK
7/4/2010 2DN  $99.00 TRAN   0            7     WEEK 7-WEEK
```

I would like the pivot table to look like this:

```
Count of Date   PREF  TRAN  DISC
7-WEEK          (Avg of Count of Date Here)
 0              (Avg of Count of Date Here)
  7/1/2010       (Count of Date Here)
  7/2/2010       (Count of Date Here)
  7/3/2010       (Count of Date Here)
  7/4/2010       (Count of Date Here)
 1-30           (Avg of Count of Date Here)
  7/1/2010       (Count of Date Here)
  7/2/2010       (Count of Date Here)
  7/3/2010       (Count of Date Here)
  7/4/2010       (Count of Date Here)
```

So in my example I want it too look like this:

```
Count of Date   PREF  TRAN  DISC
7-WEEK          0.25  0.75  0.25
 0              0.25  0.5   0.25
  7/1/2010       0     1     0
  7/2/2010       1     0     1
  7/3/2010       0     0     0
  7/4/2010       0     1     0
 1-30            0    0.25   0
  7/1/2010       0     1     0
  7/2/2010       0     0     0
  7/3/2010       0     0     0
  7/4/2010       0     0     0
```

Is there anyway to get the pivot table to do this?

If i make it "Average", then it will average the excel date, giving some nonsense number like 44000. If I create an additional column in the original raw data table, like "RoomNights" but setting it to "1" for everything (since you can only sell the room once a night per folio), then counting/summing would be the same, but again Average gives a wrong value (in this case just gives "1").